# Using flexunit with Visual Studio 2008 IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2008, flexunit4

Is it possible to use flexunit with Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke flexunit with nAnt, so technically yes, but... why?

Comment: all my unit test cases for a dif component on this project have been done on visual studio, this particular component has been developed using flex. i'm looking to see if i can be consistent throughout. if you have any suggestions please share, and, thank you so much for answering :).

Comment: It doesn't really matter what tool you are using to do your development, source is source, you can use test managers in any environment that will let you run a process, Visual Studio allows this in a few different ways, personally I would recommend you start looking at continuious integration and have your build/test cycle done on every check-in by that. A good choice is TeamCity or Hudson.